# Node JS + Express - serve static files, with data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not a huge fan of server side rendering, ie, I don't like using template engines and such. I'd rather have the client control the display, and the server just serve static files and data.

I've designed my main web page to be a single page app. On first load, the user is presented with a login form and everything else is hidden. If they log in successfully, it hides the login and displays the rest of the app. Now I've implemented cookies so they only need to log in once. The trouble is, I can't think of a way for the client to know that it is logged in before displaying the login form.

When the client requests `/` I do this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        if(req.cookies.token){
            app.locals.userManager.loginUserWithToken(req.cookies.token, req.ip, req.headers['user-agent'])
        }
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + './../public/index.html'));
    });
```

What can I do to tell the browser that the user is logged in and the login form does not need to be displayed? Can I send some kind of pre-data along with the response? I guess not because I am just sending a file..

Comment: I assume that if the user manipulates the page to get past the login form without actually logging in (since the "rest of the app" is there, just hidden), they still won't have access to anything that an un-logged-in user shouldn't have access to? E.g., all gate-keeping is ultimately server-side, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could include a second cookie with the response, which the code in the SPA could use to decide whether to show login or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to develop SPA with static files and not a framework like react.

use `bcrypt` module to hash user id. when user logged in, send it to front-end and save it in local storage. 
on page load check local storage. for more secure app you can send an ajax request to server on page load and check hashed id for verification.

p.s. this solution is kinda messy and not secure since you will send all of your data as a static page for user. if you really like server side rendering you can check `next.js`.

Comment: I went through `next.js` and I just.. is there something wrong with me?  This seems like the wrong way to code. We seem to be making things so complex these days (just navigating pages requires a whole process..!). I think I will just show a loading screen first, check if the user is logged in, and voila. Dunno why I didn't think of it.